# Screening unstable coefficient's sign after removing another variable from regression

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

I am trying to test which variable's sign is going to change (either + or -) after I remove another variable from `lm()` in R.
Here's my data:

```r
df <- data.frame(T1 = c(70,65,87,67,70,65,87,67,69),
                 T2 = c(95,88,91,65,87,67,70,65,101),
                 T3 = c(64,65,53,74,91,65,87,67,70),
                 T4 = c(56,64,75,65,67,70,65,87,67),
                 T5 = c(640,650,530,740,910,650,870,670,700),
                 NYC = c(50,51,78,88,74,91,65,87,67))
```

I've written the following code:

```r
mymod <- lm(NYC~.,df)
storage <- c()
for(i in names(df[ , !(names(df) %in% "NYC")])) {
  myupdate <- update(mymod,. ~ . -get(i))
  mysign <- mymod$coefficients[!names(mymod$coefficients) %in% c(get(i),'(Intercept)')]*
    myupdate$coefficients[!names(myupdate$coefficients) %in% '(Intercept)']
  storage <- c(storage,names(mysign[mysign]<0))  
}
```

So, my response variable is NYC, and I would like to remove `T1` first and update the regression and check if any signs of variables (i.e. T2,T3,T4 and T5) change compared to the full model (i.e. `lm(NYC~T1+T2+T3+T4+T5,df))`. Then I remove `T2` and so on. The sign of `intercept` is not important, but we keep it in the model all the time.
The logic I have thought is to check if the multiplication of full and updated models is negative. So, it shows the corresponding signs in the full and updated models are against one another. Since `(-)x(-)` or `(+)x(+)` is always positive.

Unfortunately my code throws an error:

```r
Error in get(i) : object 'T1' not found
```

The expected output may look like below:

```r
>storage
[1] "T3" "T5"
```

I don't know how to fix it, or if there is an efficient way of doing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tip run your code line by line, to find the exact line that causes the error. In case of a for-loop you can set `i <- "T1` and run the lines in the for-loop separately.

In this case the problem is with the `get(i)`. That is because there is no variable `T1`. That variable exists only in a data.frame. To build formula from strings I usually use `paste` combined with `as.formula`. So

```
as.formula(paste0('. ~ . - ', i))
```

If you have to use functions as `get` and `assign` there is a more practical or robust solution.

For your entire loop I would do something like:

```
covs <- setdiff(names(df), "NYC")
m0 <- lm(NYC ~ ., data = df)

res <- data.frame(cov = covs, est0 = coef(m0)[-1])

for (cov in covs) {
  m <- update(m0, as.formula(paste0(". ~ . - ", cov)))
  coefs <- coef(m)[-1]
  m <- match(res$cov, names(coefs))
  res[[cov]] <- sign(coefs[m]) == sign(res$est0)
  # OR
  # res[[cov]] <- coefs[m]
}
```

Resulting in:

```
> res
   cov        est0   T1    T2   T3   T4   T5
T1  T1 -0.11329815   NA  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
T2  T2 -0.52177372 TRUE    NA TRUE TRUE TRUE
T3  T3 -0.02237203 TRUE FALSE   NA TRUE TRUE
T4  T4  0.80376280 TRUE  TRUE TRUE   NA TRUE
T5  T5          NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA
```